# Current as a change in charge over time

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm having quite a hard time getting why we consider $I=0$ in some steady volume with nothing changing over time (because what comes in, comes out from my poor understanding).
If we do have some changes over time, why do we say $I=-\frac{dQ}{dt}$, with a minus? Considering current as a flux seems very non-intuitive for me and I will be glad for some clarifications.

Comment: What is the question here? Current is defined to be rate of flow of charge, its a name, like velocity is to displacement. I have never seen it defined with a minus, but I think this is a reference to conventional current? To avoid negative signs in calculations in circuit analysis, bearing in mind current is the flow of negatively charged electrons through a conductor, we say that positive charges are flowing in the opposite direction instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $I=\frac{dQ}{dt}$ (no minus sign) is used to define what we mean by the current through a cross-section of a conductor, or through some other surface, not necessarily, or even usually, wholly enclosing a volume. Here $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ means rate of *flow* of charge. It is an "inexact" differential in the sense that $dQ$ does not represent a small portion of some quantity *Q* belonging to a system. [That's one reason for preferring to write $I=\int_A \vec J.\vec {dA}$, that is the current density vector integrated over the cross-section or surface.] The direction of the current is the direction in which positive charge flows through the surface.

The equation $I=-\frac{dQ}{dt}$ has a different meaning. $-\frac{dQ}{dt}$ represents the rate of decrease of an amount of charge *Q* residing in some volume. $I$ is the rate of flow of charge out of the volume through a surface that completely encloses the volume. So the equation means that the rate of loss of charge from the volume is equal to the total current leaving the volume through its bounding surface.

Comment: A good example of the latter appears in the analysis of the charging and discharging of a capacitor.  The $Q$ that appears in most treatments is the charge on the capacitor, so $-dQ/dt$ indicates discharging.  This is a common "gotcha" for novices.

Comment: @garyp, FWIW, I cringe whenever I read "Q ... is the charge on the capacitor"

Comment: @AlfredCentauri That's interesting.  What bothers you about it?

Comment: @garyp  Yes indeed. It would help if there were a different symbol for $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ meaning rate of flow of charge, for example using d with a horizontal bar through it in dQ, following how Zemansky and others represented a small quantity of work – and for much the same reason.

Comment: Charged capacitors have no charge on them in the usual sense!

Comment: @garyp, what bothers me about it is that $Q$ *isn't* the charge on the capacitor - a charged capacitor is like a charged battery (cell). Both are electrically neutral and both have stored energy. The energy stored in a capacitor comes from the *separation* of charge so that one plate has +Q charge on it while the other has -Q charge.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited context you've provided, I can only assume you're having some conceptual difficulty with the *conservation of electric charge* as it relates to the amount of charge within some volume.

If we consider a (fixed) *closed* surface (not necessarily a physical surface) bounding some volume, and the quantity of some substance within the volume, there are two possible reasons that the quantity can change with time:

(1) there is a net flow of the substance across the bounding surface

(2) there is a net creation / destruction of the substance within the volume

If we denote with $I$ the net *outward* flow of the substance across the boundary surface, and if we denote with $\iota$ the net rate at which the substance is created within the volume, then the rate of change of the quantity $Q$ of the substance within the volume is

$$\dot Q = -I + \iota$$

If the substance is conserved (cannot be created or destroyed), e.g., electric charge, then

$$\dot Q = -I$$

That is, if there is a net outward flow of charge across the surface bounding the volume, the total amount of charge within the volume *decreases* with time.

Note that the sign would change if $I$ were the net *inward* flow of charge instead.